# git branch -r --merged displays un-merged branches

Tags: git, terminal

I need to find the most recently merged branch into master. So I'm using

```
git branch -r --merged master
```

But the problem is that it lists the unmerged branches as well.

I run this on a fresh clone of the repository but the unmerged branches still show up. Can someone tell me what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here the branch you're comparing every branch to is `master`, your local version.

You might have an obsolete local ref. To rule it out, you can

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

then retry your initial command, and output *should* be only branches whose tip is in `master`'s history (or is reachable from `master`'s tip, if you prefer)

Another cause could have been obsolete refs for the other branches as well, of course, but the above `pull` is implying a `fetch` so the remote-tracking branches will be ok too.

---

Note : I assumed you only have `master` in local and the branches you're comparing against are remote ones, like `-r` suggested. If in the contrary you have local branches, and some show up unexpectedly in the "merged" output, be sure to update *their* definitions too.

Comment: I figured out what my issue was. All those branches had the same commit hash in between them i.e. I created 10 branches but I did not push any changes onto them so they were identical to master and hence showed up as `merged`. Once I added a few commits, the output showed up correctly as expected

Comment: @Saturnian Thanks for the feedback :-)